# changing configuration files with Group Policy

Tags: windows, batch-file, gpo

Trying to wrap my head around a problem.  Using Owncloud sync client, default bandwidth settings are 'unlimited' and I need to set an enterprise to use a configured limit.  This is possible in the owncloud.cfg file, and the specific section is seen here:

```
...

[Bandwidth]
maxUpload=10
maxDownload=50
useMaxUpload=0
useMaxDownload=0

...
```

What I want is to set new values in the maxUp/maxDn values, and set the useMax values to '1'.

All I have been able to come up with is to write a logon script that runs a script to check the file and set the [Bandwidth] section in case a user has changed the pushed settings.

The rub here is that .bat files are terrible at this.  I can't use powershell as I cannot verify that all users have it on their machines, but if someone wants to correct me on that, there are mostly Win 10, but it's the Win 7 that I fear cannot do PS scripts.

Anyhoo, I'm not a big M$ Winderp user and would have sed/awk'd this issue without any hassle on a *nix box.  I don't want to install cygwin or any third party, just use whats on the OS.

Can anyone please 1. Point me to the correct tool, like vbs or ps or .bat or .cmd etc.  and 2. Offer a simple starting point to where I can build from?  I intend to push this from a GPO.

EDIT- So I'll use powershell.  Now my challenge is to write better PS scripts

```
(Get-Content %LOCALAPPDATA%\ownCloud\owncloud.cfg) -replace '^useDownloadLimit=\d$', 'useDownloadLimit=1' | Set-Content %LOCALAPPDATA%\ownCloud\owncloud.cfg   

(Get-Content %LOCALAPPDATA%\ownCloud\owncloud.cfg) -replace '^useUploadLimit=\d$', 'useUploadLimit=1' | Set-Content %LOCALAPPDATA%\ownCloud\owncloud.cfg

(Get-Content %LOCALAPPDATA%\ownCloud\owncloud.cfg) -replace '^DownloadLimit=\d*$', 'DownloadLimit=500' | Set-Content %LOCALAPPDATA%\ownCloud\owncloud.cfg

(Get-Content %LOCALAPPDATA%\ownCloud\owncloud.cfg) -replace '^UploadLimit=\d*$', 'UploadLimit=500' | Set-Content %LOCALAPPDATA%\ownCloud\owncloud.cfg
```

EDIT 2-
For owncloud.exe, this being run from the local machine works perfectly

```
@echo off
(@echo
@echo [BWLimit]
@echo downloadLimit=500
@echo uploadLimit=500
@echo useDownloadLimit=1
@echo useUploadLimit=1) >> "%LOCALAPPDATA%\ownCloud\owncloud.cfg"

taskkill /f /im "owncloud.exe" && start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ownCloud\owncloud.exe" --logdir cv_logs --logexpire 72
REM LOGS ARE FOUND AT - C:\Users\'username'\AppData\Local|VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\ownCloud\
```

But I'm not seeing the cfg file change after a few logoff/logons
Any ideas?

Comment: you can do it with `cmd` batch file and run a loop with a timeout to check the file every few hours, minutes etc. but as far as powershell is concerned, yes, all pc's should have at least version 1 on them. how about you post the code you wrote in the logon script so I can see where we can perhaps make it work more robust?

Comment: Please note that https://stackoverflow.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill  May I please have this made live again?

Comment: @user2359452 Be patient. After your edits the question will be in the reopen queue for people to vote to reopen.